# step by step / quickest way to script to to remotely execute files

Tags: cmd, remote-access, execute

Hello i have 3 networked machine with a shared folder, i need a script on one of the machines to run a files on all 3 computers at the same time.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: schtasks? I has ability to schedule tasks on remote machine.

Comment: What is your tolerance for at the same time? Within 10 seconds of each other?

Answer (score 0):

PsExec from sysinternals

> Utilities like Telnet and remote control programs like Symantec's PC
>   Anywhere let you execute programs on remote systems, but they can be a
>   pain to set up and require that you install client software on the
>   remote systems that you wish to access. PsExec is a light-weight
>   telnet-replacement that lets you execute processes on other systems,
>   complete with full interactivity for console applications, without
>   having to manually install client software. PsExec's most powerful
>   uses include launching interactive command-prompts on remote systems
>   and remote-enabling tools like IpConfig that otherwise do not have the
>   ability to show information about remote systems.
>
> Note: some anti-virus scanners report that one or more of the tools
>   are infected with a "remote admin" virus. None of the PsTools contain
>   viruses, but they have been used by viruses, which is why they trigger
>   virus notifications.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `waitfor` to synchronize.

At the targets use `waitfor anysignalname` It will wait, until this signal is sent.

At the host (or on another cmd-prompt at one of the three targets) use `waitfor /SI anysignalname` to send the signal.